# Why H2 file database data get cleared every time

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I use H2 database for a test application, using Spring boot. Every time, when I restart the spring boot app, the data in H2 gets cleared. I am using a file instead of memory. I set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in application.properties too.
Here is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/demo
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

What am I doing wrong here. It saves data fine. But once I shut down the app, all data get cleared.

Comment: `H2` is in memory database, it will get clear for every shutdown

Comment: to persist and not clear the database on exit: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

Comment: It can write to a file too. so it will not be cleared after the shutdown. I found my mistake. look my answer below

Comment: I have the same problem with same application properties DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE fix the issue even I am using file not mem

Answer (score 5):

I found the mistake I was doing. I had data.sql file in resources and every time Spring boot starts the app, it runs this script. In that script I was dropping and recreating all the tables. Once I removed those sql statements, it works perfect. Data is persistent to the file and won't be erased after the server restart.

Comment: I dont think you have found correct mistake. For me I am not droping and creating table using data.sql, still my data was lost. Adding ```DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE``` helped to persist data even after closing the application

Answer (score 0):

By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost. To keep the database open, add ;`DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the database URL. To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual machine is alive, use `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.`; `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;`

[H2 Feature Document](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases)

Comment: You can write it to a file, so data will persistent. that is why I had this line. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/demo